# How to re-create the actions from the popup that appears if a window is hung?

Tags: c++, windows, error-handling

How can you programmatically tell windows to "Wait for the program to respond"?

This is what the popup looks like:[image]

I was thinking of sending a message to the HWND, but can't find the required message.

Comment: Why do you need to?

Comment: I am getting the HWND of an external window, and sometimes it gets stuck an I found out that pressing "Wait for the program to respond" fixes it, which is why I want to re-create it.

Comment: And I'd rather try to persuade the developers of the "external window" and the program behind it to fix their bug instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Are you sure? I'm sure I've seen these dialogs go away automatically when the program continues responding to messages.

Comment: @user253751 Now that you mention it... But still, if the process isn't currently responding to message, then sending another message doesn't make sense anyway. :)